# ASP Core: URL Rewrite not working when using AddIISUrlRewrite

Tags: c#, url-rewriting, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to re-write my URL for the 3 following condition: 
1. Remove .php extention
2. Remove .html extention
3. redirect all "www" to non-www

I was trying to use the ASP Core's Rewrite package and run the following code:

```
app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions().AddIISUrlRewrite(env.WebRootFileProvider, "files/IISUrlRewrite.xml"));
```

on files/IISUrlRewrite.xml, I have this code:

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="RemovePHP">
      <match url="^(.*).php$" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="RemoveHTML">
      <match url="^(.*).html" />
      <action type="Rewrite" url="{R:1}" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="www to non-www" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="(www.*)" negate="false"></match>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://example.com/{R:1}"></action>
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^example\.com$" negate="true"></add>
      </conditions>
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

However, this is not working. www's are not being redirected, .php are not being removed. This code works fine when I put it in my web.config file.

Also, I understand I could do the same thing using the middleware [Microsoft Documentation: Url Rewriting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting)

Thank you for the help.

Comment: is your 2nd rule ie .html page redirection working ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, no that's not working either.

Comment: Where in your project structure is exacly `files/IISUrlRewrite`? If that's in your project root, you need to use `env.ContentRootFileProvider`, using `env.WebRootFileProvider` means it would be located in `$/wwwroot/files/IISUrlRewrite`. You can also double check the file is found with any of those file providers by manually checking `fileProvider.GetFileInfo(filePath);`

Comment: Yea, it's in /wwwroot/files/IISUrlRewrite. On start, it did not throw a file not found exception, so therefore I am pretty sure it's able to locate the fire correctly.

Answer (score 12):

This usually happens when you add the **RewriteMiddleware** after configuring the static file handling using the `app.UseStaticFiles()` method: if you do that, the **RewriteMiddleware** might be superseeded by the one in charge of the static files, which could mess up your rewrite rules.

In other words, *do not* do this:

```
app.UseDefaultFiles();

app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions(...));

app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions(...)); // <- MIGHT NOT WORK AS EXPECTED
```

And do this instead:

```
app.UseDefaultFiles();

app.UseRewriter(new RewriteOptions(...));  // <- WORKS

app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions(...));
```