# Kestrel rewrite url middleware from IIS patterns

Tags: iis, kestrel-http-server

I am trying to rewrite IIS url rewrite to kestrel rewrite middleware rule, So my IIS

> 1. rewrite rule is quite simple
> 2. input: URL path after /
> 3. match: Matches
> 4. pattern: ^auth(.*)
> 5. action type: Rewrite
> 6. action url: http://localhost:6000{R:1}

So now I try to do it using Kestrel, so far I have:

```
    var rewrite = new RewriteOptions().AddRewrite(@"^auth(.*)", "/$1", false);
    app.UseRewriter(rewrite);
```

But it does not work as expected, so what can I do?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-7.0#extension-and-options Please dig further into `AddIISUrlRewrite` and that's what should work for you.

Comment: Can you post more information about your code? Here is a similar question you can use as a reference: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/44992957/13336642](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44992957/13336642).